# SQL Multiple result sets

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

[image]I am joining 4 tables to retrive but, i want to retrive result set as 2 arrays, i tried and its retriving as one result set.

Following is query

```
 select * from `services` inner join `location_services` on `location_services`.`serviceID` = `services`.`serviceID` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`locationID` = `location_services`.`locationID` inner join `clinics` on `clinics`.`clinicID` = `locations`.`clinicID` where `locations`.`clinicID` = 7
```

As shown in picture, i want to retrive

```
location id with 38 as one result set and `39` as another.
```

Follwing is my query in controller

```
public function showClinic($id)
    {
        $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
        $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
        $locationservices = Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid')
            ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
            ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID')
            ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID')
            ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id)
            ->get();

        // $newlocations = Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid')
        //     ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
        //     ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID')
        //     ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID')
        //     ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id)
        //     ->get();
        return view('clinic.show')->with(['locations' =>  $locations  ,'clinic'=>$clinic , 'services'=> $locationservices]);

    }
```

Here there are multiple clin

Comment: add one more line `->groupBy('services.serviceName')` after `where` condition

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::group_by() error

Comment: check updated comment

Comment: Bro , same error is showing

Comment: is this your updated query `Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid')
            ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
            ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID')
            ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID')
            ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id)
            ->groupBy('services.serviceName')
            ->get();`

Comment: yes now when i did var_dump($services) its returning as [ ],am not getting any data

Comment: ->where('services.serviceName') , here you have used  where condition , not group by

Comment: check above query

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'directory.locations.locationID' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `services`.`serviceName` as `servicename`, `locations`.`locationID` as `locid` from `services` inner join `location_services` on `location_services`.`serviceID` = `services`.`serviceID` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`locationID` = `location_services`.`locationID` inner join `clinics` on `clinics`.`clinicID` = `locations`.`clinicID` where `clinics`.`clinicID` = 7 group by `services`.`serviceName`)  error

Answer (score 0):

Add `->groupBy('location_services.locationID')` to your query, so you can group the same locationID as one record:

```php
public function showClinic($id)
    {
        $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
        $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
        $locationservices = Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid')
            ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
            ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID')
            ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID')
            ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id)
            ->groupBy('location_services.locationID')
            ->get();


        return view('clinic.show')->with(['locations' =>  $locations  ,'clinic'=>$clinic , 'services'=> $locationservices]);

    }
```

And if your **mysql version is v5.7+**, you will have **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** problem,

add `modes` to mysql array in your config/database.php:

```php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            'strict' => true,
            'modes'  => [
                //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ]
        ],
```